# Android firebase get ch database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here I attached my Firebase database screenshot:

[image]

I don't know how to get all child data in Android app. Please give me some example.

[MyCoding](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YymMI9hKEoUlv5tRSsXQJCQsBr_QbDNx)

Comment: Where is the XML?

Comment: @jdweng you want my XML file

Comment: Please include code and Firebase structures as TEXT in your questions,  not images or links. Links break and if they do, it invalidates the question. Also take a sec and read [Screenshots are Evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: Also - the dates stored in the child nodes are redundant. If the date appears in the path to the data you want, that means you already know the date because you included it in the path, therefore there's no reason to also store it in the child node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display all those values of a particular date, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference ref = rootRef.child("Sreeauto").child("28-05-2018");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String date = ds.child("date").getValue(String.class);
            String incharge = ds.child("incharge").getValue(String.class);
            String qty = ds.child("qty").getValue(String.class);
            String shift = ds.child("shift").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", date + " / " + incharge + " / " + qty + " / " + shift);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output will be:

```
28-5-2018 / Karthi / 500 / A Shift
```

To get those values from all dates, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference ref = rootRef.child("Sreeauto");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            for(DataSnapshot dSnapshot : ds.getChildren()) {
                String date = dSnapshot.child("date").getValue(String.class);
                String incharge = dSnapshot.child("incharge").getValue(String.class);
                String qty = dSnapshot.child("qty").getValue(String.class);
                String shift = dSnapshot.child("shift").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("TAG", date + " / " + incharge + " / " + qty + " / " + shift);

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```